# Pandas dataframe: Splitting single-column data from txt file into multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split, text-files, multiple-columns

I have an obnoxious .txt file that is output from a late 1990's program for an Agilent instrument. I am trying to comma-separate and organize the single column of the text file into multiple columns in a pd dataframe. After some organization, the txt file currently looks like the following: See link here:
 [Organized Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7AdS.png)
Each row is indexed in a pd dataframe. The code used to reorganize the file and attempt to split into multiple columns follows:

```
quantData = pd.read_csv(epaTemp, header = None)   
trimmed_File = quantData.iloc[16:,]
trimmed_File = trimmed_File.drop([17,18,70,71,72], axis = 0)
print (trimmed_File)
###
splitFile = trimmed_File.apply( lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(',')))
print (splitFile)
```

The split function above did not get applied to all rows present in the txt file. It only `split(',')`the first row rather than all of them:

> 0  16              Compound                     R... 1
>   dtype: object

I would like this split functionality to apply to all rows in my txt file so I can further organize my data. Thank you for the help.

Comment: `trimmed_File.apply( lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(',')), axis = 1)` Have you tried this?

Comment: Thank you, that did work, although it only split the txt file into two columns... So i guess now somehow it is not registering the white space and not splitting the different columns of data correctly. If you have any other ideas let me know.

Comment: I'll have to look at your data and also please post your input data and expected output. But I am assuming you need to split the sentence into different columns based on spaces?

Comment: Hi Danny - I apologize for the late response, thank you. I've gotten sidelined from the project at work, just looking at it again. I will attempt to update the post with what you requested. Thank you.